# MUIDataTable 'customBodyRender' error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am doing a ReactJS Application, working with a rest API, and I want to test the node packages MUI-datatables, to display a list.

But I get the error : 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'customBodyRender' of undefined'

Here is my code :

```
render() {
   const columns = ["URL", "Modele"];
   const test = [
     ["Joe James", "Test Corp", "Yonkers", "NY"]
   ];
   const options = {
     filterType: 'checkbox',
   };
   return (
      <div>
         <MUIDataTable title={"Offree"} data={test} columns={columns} options={options}/>
   </div>)
   }
}
```

Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to match the amount of items in `columns` with the amount of items in `test`. Currently, you have two more items in your data, compared to your columns. For example, the following will fix:

```
    const columns = ["URL", "Modele", "thirdColumn", "fourthColumn"];
```

If you don't want to display the third and fourth column, you can set `display: false` in your column options:

```
const columns = [
        {
            name: "URL",
            options: {
                display: true
            }
        },
        {
            name: "Modele",
            options: {
                display: true
            }
        },
        {
            name: "thirdColumn",
            options: {
                display: false
            }
        },
        {
            name: "fourthColumn",
            options: {
                display: false
            }
        }

    ]
```